# Remember jQuery Tablesorter drop-down selection using jQuery Cookie?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, tablesorter, jquery-cookie

I'm using two jQuery Tablesorter drop-downs to filter results of a dynamically-generated table. When a name in either drop-down is selected, only results containing that name will show.

What I want is for jQuery Cookie to remember the last selected filter option for each drop-down before the page was reloaded. If the name "Alaina " (seen in the attached picture) was the selected option for the "Assigned to" drop-down before the user left the page, I want "Alaina" to be the default option when the user goes back to the page.

Currently when the page loads, the default "Filter" selection is loaded, and thus no results are filtered.

The output of the drop-down for the "Assigned to" column (the drop-down for the "Expeditor" column has the same structure, only its `id` is `msdrpdd20` instead of `msdrpdd21`):

```
<td>
  <div id="msdrpdd21_msddHolder" class="ddOutOfVision">
    <select id="msdrpdd21" class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="3" tabindex="-1">
      <option value=""> … </option>
      <option value="(none)"> … </option>
      <option value="Alaina"> … </option>
      <option value="Alyssa"> … </option>
      <option value="Felicita"> … </option>
      <option value="Luciana"> … </option>
      <option value="Rachel"> … </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="msdrpdd21_msdd" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" tabindex="0">
    <div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp">
      <span id="msdrpdd21_title" class="ddTitleText ">
        <span class="ddlabel">
          (none)
        </span>
        <span class="description" style="display: none;"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input id="msdrpdd21_titleText" class="text shadow borderRadius" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;"></input>
    <div id="msdrpdd21_child" class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" style="display: none;">
      <ul>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
        <li class="enabled _msddli_"> … </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

[image]

**EDIT** (07/29/13): Screenshot of Nev's cookie:

[image]

**EDIT** (08/01/13): Screenshot of Nev's revision:

[image]

Filtering of results (via [Tablesorter Filter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Widget-options)):

```
$( '#todo-list' ).tablesorter( {
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {filter_reset : '.reset'}
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nev's answer is what lead me to this point, and without his help I wouldn't have (stupidly) figured this out.

tablesorter is called with the following function:

```
$('table').tablesorter( {
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {filter_reset : '.reset'}
});
```

In order to save your last Filter selection, the following code has to be placed ***before*** the above call:

```
$('table')
    .bind('filterInit', function () {
        // check that storage utility is loaded
        if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
            // get saved filters
            var f = $.tablesorter.storage( this, 'tablesorter-filters' ) || [];
            $.tablesorter.setFilters( this, f, true );
        }
    })
    .bind('filterEnd', function () {
        if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
            // save current filters
            var f = $.tablesorter.getFilters( this );
            $.tablesorter.storage( this, 'tablesorter-filters', f );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [JQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    data = $("#payments").msDropdown().data('dd');
    if ($.cookie("table-sorter") !== null) {
        var toselect = $.cookie("table-sorter");
        data.set('selectedIndex', toselect);
    }

    $('#payments').change(function () {
        var selected = this.selectedIndex;
        // save value to cookie
        $.cookie("table-sorter", selected, { path: '/' });
    });


});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKQRj/40/) (works in Firefox but not IE). The code however works if you upload it to your own server (tested in IE).

Comment: Just tried the code, and the cookie is being changed properly whenever a new option is selected. The problem is when the page is refreshed, the saved option isn't selected on refresh: the drop-down defaults back to `Filter`. I took a screenshot of Firebug and I edited it into my OP. You can see the cookie `table-sorter` correctly set as `Alyssa`, but the default option in the drop-down is `Filter`.

Comment: Does `$('#msdrpdd21').val( toselect )` get executed?

Comment: How would I know if it gets executed if the value on refreshed is still the default `Filter`? Also, being I'm using a plugin to replace the the `<select>` drop-down with a `<div>` drop-down, would the `<div>` need to be targeted, being the "selected" class is associated with the `<div>`? See `id=msdrpdd21_child` in the OP.

Comment: Yes that might be the problem

Comment: Would you kindly be able to edit your answer to reflect `msdrdd21_child` as the target?

Comment: What was the plugin called?

Comment: I've had a look into `ms-Dropdown`. I had the same problem as you. I moved my code before the `.msDropDown()` function, and it seemed to work for me.

Comment: I just found a jsfiddle that uses 'msdropdown', so maybe working from that would be easier for you? http://jsfiddle.net/NKQRj/1/

Comment: I feel like we're getting close: The cookie is now successfully saving the selected option, and when the page is reloaded, "#msdrpdd21" shows the saved option as being selected. The issue is that the results aren't being filtered w/ the selected option on reload. You can see that "Alaina" is selected at reload, but the results beneath the drop down show all names instead of just "Alaina." I uploaded a screenshot of what it looks like now to the bottom of my OP.

Comment: Is there a function that is run when the dropdown is changed?

Comment: Yes, the Tablesorter Filter plugin is filtering the results (I'll edit the jQuery code for it into my OP): http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Widget-options

Comment: Also a discussion on saving filter results: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/146

Comment: My previous link to github solved the issue, I'll show it in an answer. Thanks for your hard work Nev.